# Having Issues Appending to Array in Processing

Tags: java, arrays, append, processing

I am trying to send an array over my serial port. The name of this array is 'send' and initially, it is empty. I want to append integers to this array but I am having issues doing so. I print the array, but it prints out nothing. Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;
String val;

void setup(){
  size(200,200);
  String portName = Serial.list()[2];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);


}

void draw(){
    //myPort.write(0);
    //println(0);

}

int i = 0;
void mouseClicked(){
     //String myStr = "RGBY"; 
     String stre = "e|1";
     String strB = "B|1";
     String strG = "G|1";
     String strD = "D|1";
     String strA = "A|1";
     String strE = "E|1";

     println(stre);

     int[] send = {2};
     append(send, 1);
     printArray(send);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Java arrays have a fixed length, you'll need to create a new array that is one longer (or use an `ArrayList`).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Please notice the [tag:processing] tag, and [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java). The `append()` function is a Processing function that appends an item to an array, exactly how you're describing.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Uhh, okay? I was just pointing out that this is a Processing question, which a lot of people miss because it's such a generic name. Not sure why that caused an attitude, but have a good day anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [reference](https://processing.org/reference/append_.html), you should be saving the result of a function call:

```
send = append(send, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to create an array of objects that would grow dynamically and the only way that worked was using **ArrayList**, it was perfect:

```
  ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

Only then was I able to use the .add and .remove to resize the array dynamically.

**Adding an object:**

```
  objTemp = new MyObject(x, y);
  myObjects.add(objTemp);
```

**Remove all objects:**

```
  for (int i = myObjects.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    myObjects.remove(i);
  }
```